# Any PHP -> jQuery libraries out there?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Have any bridge libraries been developed for PHP that provide access to the jQuery framework? Ideally it would be nice to have something fairly extensible so that creating jQuery-based content using PHP code would be fairly easy and customizeable. Does such a thing exist yet?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea to me. Javascript/jQuery are meant to do client-side stuff, so it's not going to mix well with PHP. I would imagine it will just muddy up your code and make it harder to change things around later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [pquery](http://ajaxian.com/archives/pquery-php-and-jquery)
2. [jqpie](http://ajaxian.com/archives/jqpie-jquery-php-interface-extension)
3. [jquery-php](http://jquery.hohli.com/)

There's a warmup list.

Comment: I guess [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) should also be on this list...

Answer (score 1):

So far I've found one that seems to fit the description. I haven't tried it out yet, so if anyone has any feedback or experience with this or other ones don't hesitate to post!

[PQuery](http://ajaxian.com/archives/pquery-php-and-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

[jQPie](http://ajaxian.com/archives/jqpie-jquery-php-interface-extension) might be what you're after.

> What can jQPie do?
>
> - Easily request and process data from php using $.getJSON
> - Inject php generated html into elements using $.(element).load
> - Call php functions directly from your web pages using $.jqpie
> - Call jQuery from php in respond to $.jqpie calls
> - Advanced autocomplete using jqpie_complete

Answer (score 1):

QueryPath (http://querypath.org) is a full implementation of the jQuery DOM/XML/HTML part of jQuery. QueryPath has full CSS 3 selector support (including the stuff jQuery doesn't have, like XML namespace support). It also comes with DB tools, where you can run queries and have the results inserted into the query object. And it has a template engine, too. Like jQuery, you can write custom extensions very easily.

But it definitely takes advantage of its server-side status.

The main project page is at https://fedorahosted.org/querypath. You can download it there (and see lots of examples, including RSS and SVG manipulation).

Integrating with jQuery, then, can be done easily by sending XML data of many sorts down to jQuery. (You could probably send JSON, too... never tried.) And since the server side code and the client side code both look the same, there's less of a need to learn two totally different toolkits.